Error while upgrading to .NET 8.0 for SolaceSystems.SolClient.Messaging
We are using Assembly SolaceSystems.SolClient.Messaging  in messaging applications (Streaming microservices). Our applications are deployed in OpenShift Containers. We are using C# with .NET 6.0. Everything is working good as of now.
While upgrading our applications to .NET 8.0 (from .NET 6.0), we are getting following error:
System.Runtime.Searialization.Formatters.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(System.IO.STream, object)
Is assembly of Solace - as mentioned above - is not supported on .NET 8.0? Or am I missing anything?
Any direction would be great help to me.
When I change the TargetFramework to .NET 6.0 everything works as expected without any error. But when TargetFramework is changed to .NET 8.0, above error is thrown.

Please include the full stack trace of the thrown exception.

TL;DR: We can't answer your question without the full stack trace!
The problem is BinaryFormatter. It was marked as deprecated/obsolete way back in .NET 5.0:
BinaryFormatter serialization methods are obsolete and prohibited in ASP.NET apps

Serialize and Deserialize methods on BinaryFormatter, Formatter, and IFormatter are now obsolete as warning. Additionally, BinaryFormatter serialization is prohibited by default for ASP.NET apps.

Jumping ahead to .NET 8: BinaryFormatter disabled across most project types

Starting in .NET 8, the affected methods throw a NotSupportedException at run time across all project types except Windows Forms and WPF. The APIs continue to remain obsolete (as error) across all project types, including Windows Forms and WPF.

And now in .NET 9.0: BinaryFormatter removed from .NET 9

Starting with .NET 9, we no longer include an implementation of BinaryFormatter in the runtime (.NET Framework remains unchanged). The APIs are still present, but their implementation always throws an exception, regardless of project type. Hence, setting the existing backwards compatibility flag is no longer sufficient to use BinaryFormatter.

You haven't stated whether the exception is thrown from the use of SolaceSystems.SolClient.Messaging or whether it's elsewhere in your code. The stack trace should tell you what code is attempting to use BinaryFormatter, until you/we know that we will be unable to guide you further.
